# Finding Kernel32 Base Address

Tags: c, windows, shellcode, kernel32

I've been experimenting with ways to obtain the Kernel32.dll base address in C shellcode and came up with the following method. It works on my machine running `Windows 11 Pro`, but I'm wondering how robust this method is across different versions of Windows. Here's the code:

```
#include <intrin.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef _WIN64
#define PEB_OFFSET_FROM_GS 0x60
#define PEB __readgsqword(PEB_OFFSET_FROM_GS)
#define LDR_DATA_IN_PEB_OFFSET 24
#define IN_LOAD_ORDER_MODULE_LIST_OFFSET 16
#define DLL_BASE_OFFSET 48
#else
#define PEB_OFFSET_FROM_FS 0x30
#define PEB __readfsdword(PEB_OFFSET_FROM_FS)
#define LDR_DATA_IN_PEB_OFFSET 12
#define IN_LOAD_ORDER_MODULE_LIST_OFFSET 12
#define DLL_BASE_OFFSET 24
#endif

// The sequence of modules loaded into the process typically follows the order:
// [Executable Image], [ntdll.dll], [kernel32.dll].
#define KERNEL32_BASE_ADDRESS *(uintptr_t*)(*(uintptr_t*)(*(uintptr_t*)(*(uintptr_t*)(*(uintptr_t*)(PEB + LDR_DATA_IN_PEB_OFFSET) + IN_LOAD_ORDER_MODULE_LIST_OFFSET))) + DLL_BASE_OFFSET)

int main()
{
    printf("Kernel32.dll Base Address: 0x%p\n", (void*)KERNEL32_BASE_ADDRESS);
}
```

Disassembly of KERNEL32_BASE_ADDRESS with register `edx` storing the Kernel32 base address:

```
...
mov         eax,dword ptr fs:[00000030h] ; eax = address of PEB  
mov         ecx,dword ptr [eax+0Ch]      ; ecx = address of Ldr
mov         edx,dword ptr [ecx+0Ch]      ; edx = first module entry address 
mov         eax,dword ptr [edx]          ; eax = second module entry address
mov         ecx,dword ptr [eax]          ; ecx = third module entry address
mov         edx,dword ptr [ecx+18h]      ; edx = kernel32.dll base address
...
```

Here's a single obfuscated x86/x64 macro

```
#define KERNEL32_BASE_ADDRESS *(uintptr_t*)(*(uintptr_t*)(*(uintptr_t*)(*(uintptr_t*)(*(uintptr_t*)((sizeof(uintptr_t) == 4 ? __readfsdword(0x30) : __readgsqword(0x60)) + (sizeof(uintptr_t) == 4 ? 12 : 24)) + (sizeof(uintptr_t) == 4 ? 12 : 16)))) + (sizeof(uintptr_t) == 4 ? 24 : 48))
```

Comment: How robust is a bunch of magic numbers not based on actual header files used to create dlls? What do you think?

Comment: Anyone test it on Windows 7/10?  Thanks.

Comment: You'll never get a warranty for that festival of obfuscated code.  Just load the library: auto base = (uintptr_t*)LoadLibrary(L"kernel32.dll");  No need to call FreeLibrary since kernel32 is always implicitly loaded.